# Is there a way to nest fixture parametization in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have an example where I have essentially a nested list of fixtures i.e fn2 below depends on the value of the fixture fn1 and is not know ahead of time. Each of these two functions needs to call a server to retrieve a list of parameters.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=generated_list())
def fn1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=generates_list_2(fn1))
def fn2(request):
    return request.param

def test_fn(fn2):
    assert fn2 == 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not a great answer this will work. It exploits a hook in the test generation procedure to manually generate the combinations of params.

```
def generated_list():
    return x

def generates_list_2(fn1):
    return x

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'fn1' in metafunc.fixturenames and 'fn2' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize(
            "fn1, fn2", 
            [(i, j) for i in generated_list() for j in generated_list_2(i)]
        )

@pytest.fixture()
def fn1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture()
def fn2(request):
    return request.param

def test_fn(fn1, fn2):
    assert fn2 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can nest fixtures. Just use one fixture as one of the arguments of other fixture as you would use a fixture in a test.

Your code would look like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=generated_list())
def fn1(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=generates_list_2(fn1))
def fn2(request, fn1):
    return request.param

def test_fn(fn2):
    assert fn2 == 0
```

Comment: the `fn1` argument to `generates_list_2(fn1)` is not available to the decorator function and raises an error.

Comment: You can convert the generates_list_2(fn1) function into a fixture. Pytest does not initialize the helper function outside of the test function scope.

Comment: I need to paramtrize the fixture in terms of a second fixture both of which are dynamically sized and generated. Simply creating a fixture called generates_list_2 wouldn’t work because it would return a list not a single item